# Something adding an excessive meta description

Tags: post-meta, description

I have a WordPress running with Woocommerce and a commercial theme. My problem is that something is adding an extra meta tag(og:description) and it is getting on my nerve since it's content which is completely irrelevant displays on social media while sharing our links. Here's the web address: http://pay4games.ir/ and here's the code :

```
meta property="og:description" content="[rev_slider alias="index"] جدیدترین محصولات تومان۵۷۶,۰۰۰ STAR WARS JEDI FALLEN ORDER نمره ۴٫۰۰ از ۵ افزودن به علاقه مندی ها مقایسه افزودن به سبد تماس بگیرید Watch Dogs Legion افزودن به"
```

If you view source the home page, you can find this string. I tried disabling all the plugins one by one and It got disappeared when I disabled the woocommerce! I tried using the String Locator plugin and I looked up "og:desc" and it gave me two strings from Yoast SEO but when I disable Yoast SEO, the main meta description tag disappears and the excessive one remains!!! I contacted the theme author and they came up with no resolution. I would be grateful if someone could help me finding this string's source. Best,

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
Had to disable the Open Graph option on the Theme control panel!